# Store value returned by async/await in a variable in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, async-await

I am trying the retrieve the top, right, left , bottom values of SafeAreaView in react native using this function:

If I directly console.log in my function inside the function like this

```
const SafeAreaSpecs = async () => {
    console.log(await SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView());
};
```

it gives me this:

[image]

Which is exactly what I want. But if I return `SafeAreaSpecs()` and call it somewhere else like this

```
const SafeAreaSpecs = async () => {
    return await SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView();
};

...
...
...

console.log(SafeAreaSpecs());
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see, i can still access `safeAreaInsets` but I can't figure out how to get rid of _40. _65, _55, _72. What is the proper way of storing and calling the returned value?

I have looked at this post [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but it didn't help. not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Quentin unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. I am still getting the same result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/5508175 This answer is the one what you are looking for. See the section on **ES2016 (ES7)**